# JS function as simple as it gets, hyperlink syntax

Tags: javascript, function, syntax, call

Can someone explain why, [in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/smkqW/2/), the function is not firing?  I've stripped it down to the simplest thing and I must have typo or wrong syntax for hyperlink.

JS

```
function takePic(type){
    alert(type);
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="takePic('1');">Track Progress</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `onLoad` to `no wrap (head)` in the "choose framework" dropdown. With onLoad, the function is wrapped in another function and does not have global scope.

http://jsfiddle.net/smkqW/3/

Comment: Do I need to do something different on my server?  I just have regular settings

Comment: @user1260310 Show your actual markup, so we can see why `takePic` doesn't have global scope or whatever the problem is.

Comment: It appears the problem in my script was elsewhere.  I tried the full then stripped down version on jsfiddle to debug but got tripped up by the framework issue.  Thanks!